# Getting XML child elements -- include tag names

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse some XML using `NSXMLParser` on the iPhone.

When I detect the element I want, I would like to have everything *as*  *is* between the start element and end element.

For example, given:

```
<A>
    <K>
        <C>
            <D>dddd</D>
        </C>
        <E> eeee </E>
    </K>
    <F> ffff </f>
</A>
```

I would like to specify K

And receive:

```
    <C> 
        <D> dddd </D>
    </C>
    <E> eeee </E>
```

However, currently NSXMLParser ignores all the `<`, `>`, and attributes.
What do I put in the delegate methods to make sure I get everything as is in between the tags I specify?

Here is what I have right now:

```
//---when the start of an element is found---
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict {

    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"ns11:createNewPrincipalResponse"])
    {
        elementFound = YES;
        NSLog(@"PrincResp FOUND");
    }
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (elementFound)
    {
        [parseResults appendString: string];
    }
}


//---when the end of element is found---
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ns11:createNewPrincipalResponse"])
    {
        //---displays the country---
        NSLog(@"\n******************\nParse Results...\n*************\n\n%@",parseResults);
        [parseResults setString:@""];
        token = [NSString stringWithString:parseResults];
        elementFound = FALSE; 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use columnNumber, lineNumber parser's methods to get the location where your element starts (i.e. store them as column1, line1 in didStartElement for the element you look for), then when that element ends, in didEndElement, get the column2 and line2 again and then just cut the text from the original XML from (line1, column1) to (line2, column2).

Quite hacky but it'll probably work.

Edit: to extract text you could do something along these lines:

```
__block int lineNumber = 0;
__block NSMutableString* result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];

[str enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString* line, BOOL* stop) {

if(lineNumber == line1) {
    [result appendString:[line substringFromIndex:column1]];
}
if(lineNumber > line1 && lineNumber < line2) [result appendString:line];

if(lineNumber == line2) {
    [result appendString:[line substringToIndex:column2]];
}
lineNumber++;
if(lineNumber > line2) *stop = YES;

}];
```

I don't know if the parser's position when the element starts/ends is at the beginning or at the end of that element - you may need to either skip it yourself or, if the position is at the end of the element, check if column1/column2 are not outside the line (in which case just don't add anything). Also, if you need to preserve newline characters, you'll need to add them yourself (instead of appendString:str use appendFormat:"%@\n", str)

Comment: OK, I successfully got the column and line numbers, any idea which method I could use to extract a substring from certain a column and line to another column and line?

Comment: Thanks. Your code does the trick. However, the column and line numbers returned by the parser or not the right indices :(. It may have something to do that the input to the parser is data whereas the above code works with strings.

Comment: Yeah, because the column number refers to the nesting level, rather then the actual line in the text, sorry, my mistake. If the line number is incorrect, too, then I guess you may have to try another parsers as others suggest... Or if you only need to get the text between two tags, then perhaps you don't need the XML parser at all, just do a regex match?

Comment: Thank you good sir. I was too narrow minded to realize that regex was all I needed. RegexKitLite seems to be one of the simplest library (iOS can't seem to handle regex on its own).

Comment: you're welcome. BTW, there actually is regex support in iOS - check out NSRegularExpression (although it is only available since iOS 4.0, so if you need to support earlier versions then a third-party component is in order).

Comment: Yep, I used the built int NSRegularExpression. Works fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

NSXmlParser is fairly horrible to use. Have you tried using [LibXML](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html) for parsing instead? Then you can use [XPath](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xpath%20tutorial) to query the XML, which is much simpler and a much more standard way of parsing XML documents.